# Structure timestamped data for lookup

Tags: java

I am looking for the best way to store timestamped device movement data so that I can visually play back this data in another program.
I want to be able to lookup a datatime and return any records that match that time.

The raw data comes from a csv file from a 3rd party system.
Example below

```
+------------+---------------------+-----------+--------+--------+--------+----------+---------+
| TIMESTAMP  |      DATETIME       | DEVICE_ID |   X    |   Y    |   Z    | VELOCITY | HEADING |
+------------+---------------------+-----------+--------+--------+--------+----------+---------+
| 1499881590 | 2017-07-12T17:46:30 | VEC204    | 35.657 | 22.093 | 71.626 |    11.09 |  5.4002 |
| 1499881590 | 2017-07-12T17:46:30 | VEC259    | 39.802 | 70.167 | 59.055 |     2.88 |  3.4894 |
| 1499881593 | 2017-07-12T17:46:33 | VEC200    | 54.004 | 32.068 | 48.099 |     3.63 |  5.8757 |
| 1499881593 | 2017-07-12T17:46:33 | VEC258    | 39.702 | 98.668 | 44.046 |     3.97 |   5.498 |
| 1499881594 | 2017-07-12T17:46:34 | VEC205    | 87.904 | 55.515 | 53.633 |     2.27 |  5.8746 |
| 1499881595 | 2017-07-12T17:46:35 | VEC253    | 69.882 | 72.559 | 51.034 |     5.67 |  3.2116 |
+------------+---------------------+-----------+--------+--------+--------+----------+---------+
```

There may be tens of thousands of records in the 3rd party system.
The challenge I have is that for any datetime there may be multiple devices to be updated (i.e. line 1 and 2, line 3 and 4).

I have looked at storing the data in a class/list or a map.
However I have not been able to fugure out a way to return multiple records when given a datetime.

One possible way I thought the returned data may look (I will send the data to the output system in JSON)

```
2017-07-12T17:46:30
    | VEC204    | 35.657 | 22.093 | 71.626 |    11.09 |  5.4002 |
    | VEC259    | 39.802 | 70.167 | 59.055 |     2.88 |  3.4894 |
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: My current idea to to query the stored data every second.

Comment: `Map<Date, List<Stuff>>` or a guava `Multimap` ?

Comment: Thank you, the guava Multimap is perfect.